Clause Density for guaranteed Easy (2, 3) SAT Cases
It is known that its NP-Complete to decide the satisfiability of 3-SAT instances in which every variable occurs four times.
Now given a (2, 3)-SAT instance where each clause has length 2 or 3. Moreover we are promised that the problem instance has no dummy clauses i.e. one or more clauses or constraint that is redundant and can be removed.
Is there a non trivial Clause to Variable ratio for which the problem is guaranteed to be easy i.e. solvable in polynomial time. Since the ratio of 2 SAT vs 3 SAT clauses can change the nature of the problem, if possible please specify that how changes in that affects the easy cases for Clause to Variable ratio?
